# Posts are not displaying correctly after deactivate

Tags: php, html, laravel

So, I have a problem with displaying for a few posts.After a post was deactivated, on main isn't showing anymore, but the space is still here, even if I have an `@if` condition.By default, on my page I have 7 posts on every page, but here is remaining only the posts which is activated ( table `event`, column `activate`)

**Here is the code from main**

```
    <div class="clearfix margin-bottom-20"><hr></div>

                <!-- News v3 -->
                @foreach($events as $event)
        @if($event->active != 1)
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 sm-margin-bottom-20">
                            <div class="easy-block-v1">
                                <a href="{{ url('topic') }}/{{ $event->category->category_url }}">
                                    <div class="easy-block-v1-badge rgba-{{ $event->category->color }} noticeboard-topic-category">
                                        <i class="icon-hotel-restaurant-183 u-line-icon-pro fa-"></i> / {{ $event->category->category }}
                                    </div>
                                </a>


                                <?php
                                    $video_content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $event->information);
                                    preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $video_content, $video);
                                ?>

                                <?php
                                    $match = '';
                                    $str = $event->information;
                                    $start = "<iframe src='";
                                    $end = "' width='100%' height='281'></iframe>";

                                    $pattern = sprintf(
                                        '/%s(.+?)%s/ims',
                                        preg_quote($start, '/'), preg_quote($end, '/')
                                        );

                                    if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
                                        list(, $match) = $matches;
                                    }
                                ?>
                                @if(isset($match) && $match != '')
                                    <iframe src="{{ $match }}" width='100%' height='250'></iframe>
                                @elseif(isset($video[1]))
                                    <iframe src="{{ $video[1] }}" width='100%' height='250'></iframe>
                                @else

                                    <?php preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $event->information, $image); ?>
                                    @if(isset($image['src']))
                                        <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ $image['src'] }}" alt=""> -->

                                        <?php $img = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $image['src']); ?>
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ url('ass/336/212?'.$img) }}" alt="">
                                    @else

                                        <?php $img = "thumbnail/".$event->user->profile_picture; ?>
                                        @if(@getimagesize($img))
                                            <img src="{{ url('ass/336/212?'.$img) }}" alt='' />
                                        @else
                                            <?php $img = "assets/img/main/img12.jpg"; ?>
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ url('ass/336/212?'.$img) }}" alt="">
                                        @endif
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                            </div>




                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7 news-v3">
                            <div class="news-v3-in-sm no-padding">

                                <h2><a href="{{ url('view-event') }}/{{ $event->id }}_{{ Slugify::slugify($event->subject) }}">{{ $event->subject }}</a></h2>
                                <ul class="list-inline" style="right: 10px;position: relative">

                                    <li style="font-style: normal !important">
                                    <li style="font-style: normal !important">



                                    @if($event->user->role[0]->pivot->role_id == 1)
                                    <i style="margin-right: 2px;margin-left: 3px;font-size: 11px" class="icon-user"></i>
                                    @else
                                    <i style="margin-right: 2px;margin-left: 3px;font-size: 11px" class="icon-hotel-restaurant-172 u-line-icon-pro fa- fa-lg"></i>
                                    @endif
                <a style="margin-left: 2px" href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $event->user->username }}">{{ $event->user->username }}</a></li>
                                    <li style="font-style: normal !important"><i style="margin-right: 3px" class="icon-hotel-restaurant-183 u-line-icon-pro fa-"></i> <a href="{{ url('view-all-event') }}">Event</li>

                                    <li style="font-style: normal !important"><i style="margin-right: 3px" class="icon-notebook fa-"></i> <a href="{{ url('topic') }}/{{ $event->category->category_url  }}">{{ $event->category->category }}</a></li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                <?php
                                    $information = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $event->information);
                                    $Output = preg_replace('/<iframe.*?\/iframe>/i','', $information);
                                ?>

                                <p>{{ str_limit(trim(strip_tags(preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $Output))), 200) }}</p>

                                <ul class="social-icons social-icons-color social-cu-icons" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="social-cu">

                                        <li class="facebook_share share_link" link="{{ url('view-event') }}/{{ $event->id }}_{{ Slugify::slugify($event->subject) }}" name="{{ $event->subject }}" description="{{ $event->subject }}">
                                            <a href="#" data-original-title="Facebook" class="rounded social_facebook"></a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="google_share share_link" link="{{ url('view-event') }}/{{ $event->id }}_{{ Slugify::slugify($event->subject) }}" name="{{ $event->subject }}" description="{{ $event->subject }}">
                                            <a href="#" data-original-title="Google Plus" class="rounded social_googleplus"></a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="twitter_share share_link" link="{{ url('view-event') }}/{{ $event->id }}_{{ Slugify::slugify($event->subject) }}" name="{{ $event->subject }}" description="{{ $event->subject }}">
                                            <a href="#" data-original-title="Twitter" class="rounded social_twitter"></a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="whatapp_share share_link" link="{{ url('view-event') }}/{{ $event->id }}_{{ Slugify::slugify($event->subject) }}" name="{{ $event->subject }}" description="{{ $event->subject }}">
                                            <a href="whatsapp://send?text={{ url('view-event') }}/{{ $event->id }}_{{ Slugify::slugify($event->subject) }}">
                                                <img class="img-responsive social_whatsapp" src="{{ asset('/assets/img/icons/social/Whatsapp.png') }}" alt="">
                                            </a>
                                        </li>

                                    </div>


                                </ul>

                                <ul class="post-shares post-shares-lg">
                                    <li ><a href="#"><i class="rounded-x fa fa-comments-o  "><span>{!! $event->event_comment_count !!}</span></i></a></li>

                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="rounded-x icon-magnifier-add" ><span>{!! $event->views !!}</span></i></a></li>

                                    <li class="changeview" value="{{ $event->id }}" id="changeview"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="return loginConf();"><i class="rounded-x  icon-like "><span class="like_{{ $event->id }}">{!! $event->event_like_count !!}</span></i></a></li>

                                    <li class="share-link"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="rounded-x icon-share"></i></a></li>

                                </ul>
                                <br>
                                <a href="{{ url('view-event') }}/{{ $event->id }}_{{ urlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', $event->subject)) }}">Read more...</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/end row-->
                    <!-- End News v3 -->

                    <div class="clearfix margin-bottom-20"><hr></div>
          @endif
                @endforeach
```

**My controller**

```
public function viewAllEvent($category_id = null,$event_type_id = null,$country_id = null,$starting_date = null,$username = null,$search = null,$page = null)
    {

        // $eventrecommended = Event::with('user','category','country','event_type','event_like')->withCount('event_like','event_comment')->whereHas('user.contact', function ($query) use ($id) {
        //                 $query->where('contacts.user_id', '=', $id);
        //             })->orWhere('events.public', '=', 1)->orWhere('events.user_id', '=', $id);
        // if($page == ""){
        //     return redirect('view-all-event/1');
        // }

            $data = $this->data;

            $data['title'] = "View All Event";
            $data['breadcrumbs'] = "Events";

            $page = Input::get('page');
            $perPage = 7;
            $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

            $data['evnetTypeList'] =  \App\EventType::all();
            $data['countryList'] = [''=>'Country'] + \App\Country::lists('country','code')->toArray();

            $data['category'] = Input::get('category');
            $data['event_type'] = Input::get('event_type');
            $data['country'] = Input::get('country');
            $data['starting_date'] = Input::get('starting_date');
            $username = Input::get('username');
            $search = Input::get('search');
            $data['login_user'] = $username;
            $data['search'] = $search;





            $categoryID =  \App\Category::pluck('id');


            $event = Event::with('user','category','country','event_type')->withCount('event_like','event_comment')->whereHas('user', function($query) {
                        $query->where('deleted_at', '=', null);
                    })->whereIn('category_id',$categoryID);



            $eventrecommended = Event::with('user','category','country','event_type','event_like')->whereHas('user', function($query) {
                    $query->where('deleted_at', '=', null);
                })->withCount('event_like','event_comment')->whereIn('category_id',$categoryID);


            if ($user = Sentinel::check())
            {
                if(!$user->inRole('admins'))
                {
                    $id = $user->id;

                    $event = $event->Where(function($query1) use($id){
                            $query1->where('public','=', 1)->orWhereHas('user.contact', function ($query) use ($id) {
                                $query->where('user_id', '=', $id);
                                })->orWhere('user_id','=',$id);
                    });

                    $eventrecommended = $eventrecommended->Where(function($query1) use($id){
                            $query1->where('public','=', 1)->orWhereHas('user.contact', function ($query) use ($id) {
                                $query->where('user_id', '=', $id);
                                })->orWhere('user_id','=',$id);
                    });
                }
            }
            else{
                $event = $event->where('public','=', 1);
                $eventrecommended = $eventrecommended->where('public','=', 1);

            }


            return view('event.view_all_event',$data);
    }
```

[image][image]

And in the second photo is my noticeboard, which I have same problem...

Comment: Is that supposed to be an actual screenshot, or did you add the black rectangle and red “deactivated” text in an image editor? Nothing in the code you have shown appears to be outputting “deactivated” anywhere.

Comment: @04FS the black box using image editor, but where is the section that he print posts i can't find it

Comment: Also, fix your broken HTML. `<li style="font-style: normal !important"> <li style="font-style: normal !important">` - I doubt that you actually want to _nest_ list items here, and even if that was the intention, it would still be missing UL or OL in between those two.

Comment: could you provide us with your controller method that handle this view ?

Comment: `@if($event->active != 1)` this is the code for hiding the posts which has 1 at column `active`. The post with black rectangle is deactivated, but somehow the space is still here.

Comment: @Joseph, sure, check my updated controller please.

Comment: @04FS I fixed my html but still has no effect.

Comment: add to your `$event` in your controller `where('active', 0)` and delete the if statment in your view

Comment: Yes, it's working fine right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `$event` in your controller

```
where('active', 0)
```

and delete the if statment in your view

```
 @if($event->active != 1)
 @endif
```